# Angles in a Rocker bogie system

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, rocker-bogie

How do you select the following two angles in the design of a Rocker bogie system:

1. Angle between two arms of the main rocker, and;
2. Angle between two arms in the bogie.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't think the angles matter, aside from a structural load analysis standpoint. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocker-bogie) for images of various implementations.